# Can this calculator be made shorter and more compact?

Tags: python, calculator

Is there a way to make my calculator function simpler and easier to read?
I tried looping it, but all in all it looks too complicated somehow.

```py
def calculator():
    while True:
        calc = input("Enter 'add', 'sub', 'mul' or 'div': ")

        if calc == 'add':
            first = float(input("First number: "))
            second = float(input("Second number: "))
            result = first + second
            print("Result:", result)
            break
        elif calc == 'sub':
            first = float(input("First number: "))
            second = float(input("Second number: "))
            result = first - second
            print("Result: ", result)
            break
        elif calc == 'mul':
            first = float(input("First number: "))
            second = float(input("Second number: "))
            result = first * second
            print("Result: ", result)
            break
        elif calc == 'div':
            first = float(input("First number: "))
            second = float(input("Second number: "))
            if second != 0:
                result = first / second
                print("Result: ", result)
                break
            else:
                print("It's not possible to divide by zero. Please try again.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect variables. Please try again.")

if  __name__=="__main__":
    calculator()
```

Comment: [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) provides functions for basic math operations, so you get rid of most `if/else` blocks.

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok thank you to you both.

Comment: Even if you were't using operator, it would be more efficient to pull out the two input statements:
            first = float(input("First number: "))  
            second = float(input("Second number: "))  
and put them just after the line calc = input(. . .

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a dictionary that acts as a mapping between user input and the associated operation to make life easier.

The *while* loop will terminate when input is empty.

With judicious use of exception handlers you only need one *if* statement as follows:

```
import operator

FMAP = {
    "add": operator.add,
    "sub": operator.sub,
    "mul": operator.mul,
    "div": operator.truediv,
    #"pow": operator.pow,
    #"mod": operator.mod,
    #"fdv": operator.floordiv,
}

def options():
    first, *middle, last = FMAP.keys()
    _options = f"Enter '{first}'"
    for key in middle:
        _options += f", '{key}'"
    return _options + f" or '{last}': "


while calc := input(options()):
    if func := FMAP.get(calc):
        try:
            x = float(input("Enter value for x: "))
            y = float(input("Enter value for y: "))
            print("Result:", func(x, y))
        except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        print("Unrecognised operation")
```

Note how, by using a dictionary to "drive" the code, one can easily add more functionality simply by editing the FMAP dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
import operator


def calculator():
    while True:
        calc = input("Enter 'add', 'sub', 'mul' or 'div': ")

        # rename div to truediv in order to use the function from operator
        calc = 'truediv' if calc == 'div' else calc
        first = float(input("First number: "))
        second = float(input("Second number: "))

        # function reference from operator, None as default if not matching function found!
        func = getattr(operator, calc, None)

        if not func:
            print("No math operator found!")
            continue

        if calc == 'div' and second == 0:
            print("It's not possible to divide by zero. Please try again.")
            continue

        result = func(first, second)
        print("Result:", result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    calculator()
```

Out:

```
Enter 'add', 'sub', 'mul' or 'div': div
First number: 6
Second number: 2
Result: 3.0
Enter 'add', 'sub', 'mul' or 'div': add
First number: 4
Second number: 13
Result: 17.0
```